# Loop through dynamic variable names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have dynamic variables like:

```
var4 = 56
var7 = 23
var32 = 53
...
var645 = 21
```

How can I loop through these in JavaScript so I can push each of these values in an array `vars`?

Comment: depends on what scope the variables are in ?

Comment: They are in global namespace window

Comment: I'd suggest to start with an array in the first place if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but you must know the first and the last "index" in the name of variables "var"

```
var var0 = 0;
var var1 = 10;
var var2 = 20;
// var var3 = 30; // <--- this not exist !
var var4 = 40;


var vars = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    try {
    vars.push(eval("var" + i));
  } catch(ex) { }
}
```

[This is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgd66zfj/)

Answer (score 0):

check this [pen](http://codepen.io/gurvinder372/pen/qbrxzZ)

```
var var4 = 56;
var var7 = 23;
var var32 = 53;
//...
var var645 = 21;

var arr = [];
var currentScope = window;
//currentScope = parent.frames[2].window.location;
for( var key in currentScope )
{
  console.log(key);
 if (key.indexOf( "var" ) == 0 )
 {
   console.log( "RELEVANT " + key );
   var suffix = parseInt( key.split( "var" ).join( "" ) );
   if ( !isNaN( suffix ) )
   {
    arr.push( suffix );
   }
 }
}
console.log( arr );
```